# input builtin function does not work correctly when run concurrently with msvcrt.getwch

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a function for my console app which should listen to keypresses with `msvcrt.getwch()`
but when I run it concurrently with the 'input' builtin function, something
blocks the first character entered after the listener has stopped working from showing
up in the terminal.

I.e. if I enter 'asdf' and the 'a' keypress is captured by msvcrt.getwch() then the 's'
won't be printed (tested with python2.7, python3.6):

```
C:\>keys.py
enter anything
keypress: a        # I pressed "a"
df                 # I pressed "s" "d" "f", but why "s" didn't show up here?
you entered: sdf   # note the "s" was captured by `input()` func
```

The program:

```
import threading
import msvcrt
import time

def keypress_listener():
  key = msvcrt.getwch()
  print('keypress: '+key)

def start_keypress_listener():
  t = threading.Thread(target=keypress_listener)
  t.daemon = True
  t.start()

def input_prompt():
  i = input('enter anything\n')
  print('you entered: '+i)

def main():
  start_keypress_listener()
  time.sleep(1)
  input_prompt()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your program and leisurely enter `asdf`, this is the output I get:

```
enter anything
keypress: a
df
you entered: sdf
```

This is the same as yours. Without knowing the internals of Python, it is clear that Python's `input` function has "priority" over or runs at a lower level than the `getwch` function so once function `input_prompt` starts running it grabs whatever keyboard input there is before `getwch` has a chance to.

Comment: but the `getwch` had already returned at that point, it doesn't listen to any keypresses after the first `a`. But yes the question is somehow tied to the python internals... I hope someone knows some workaround for this

Comment: @Bob: True. In fact, I missed the point entirely that function `keypress_listener` was not looping but was returning immediately after consuming one character. Consequently, my answer above was based on that erroneous assumption. If, however, you type the `asdf` quickly  (or increase the number of seconds on the call to `sleep`) so that the 4 characters are typed before `input_prompt` is run, then the character `s` will be displayed.